# Input data to JSON into Object inside an Array

Tags: php, json

I'm playing around with JSON. Suppose I have this data inside my users.json:

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Aegon Targaryen",
            "activation_key" :"18494810491048adcf"
        },

        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Jamie Lanister",
            "activation_key" : "756883"
        },

        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Brandon Stark",
            "activation_key" : "12984819849r94fr2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I count how many objects inside this "users" array?. I want to input another object such as

```
{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Arya Stark",
    "activation_key" : "2471984919edr2"
}
```

after the last object, but I haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: 'users.length' , 'users.push(new obj data)' ? What language?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this with `count()`

```
 $youJson = file_get_contents('Path');


 $data = json_decode($yourJson,true);
```

now you can simply get users `count($data['users'])`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$b=json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'), true);


echo " total number of objects = ".count($b->users);
//var_dump($b); // you can see details of $b from here

// Append the new object to users array 
$new_obj=new Stdclass();
$new_obj->id="4";
$new_obj->name="Arya Stark";
$new_obj->activation_key="2471984919edr2";

$b->users[]=$new_obj;

//var_dump($b); // you can see that the new object is added  here
```

Uncomment the `var_dump` lines to see the full structure of the `$b`.

BTW `Stdclass` allows you to create an anonymous object

Answer (score 0):

You could count the amount of users with `count` and push data at the and of the array with `[] =` or `array_push`

```
$file = 'users.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
// count users
$countOfUsers = count($data['users']);
// add an new user
$data['users'][] = [
    'id' => $countOfUsers + 1,
    'name' => 'some name',
    'activation_key' => 'some key'
];
// write back
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode`

Like:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/json_file'));
```

Then

```
$users = count($data->users);

echo $users;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you’ve read you Json file to php as $json

1) Transfer $json String to array by

```
$json_array = json_decode($json);
```

2) Count the user

```
$user_count = count($json_array->user);
```

3) Add new user

3.1 create a new use object

```
$new_user = array()
$new_user["id"] = "4";
$new_user["name"] = "Arya Stark";
$new_user["activation_key"] = "2471984919edr2”;
```

3.2 push to user object

```
$json_array->user[] = $new_user;
```